# selectedItemId doesn't work anymore after androidx.navigation:navigation library update

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have the following code:

```
activityBinding.bottomNav.selectedItemId = R.id.myFragment
```

that was working fine with `androidx.navigation:navigation-*` version 2.3.5 but is not working with version 2.4.2 and any other 2.4.* version.

I've searched everywhere but I haven't found a solution to make it work (also alternative code like `menu.findItem(R.id.myFragment).isChecked = true` didn't work).

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the new library, if with the navigator you set a fragment as starting fragment and you select with selectedItemId the same fragment, the result will be that you'll click on it but nothing will happen.

Putting the starting fragment in the nav_graph to something else and then selecting the right one using `selectedItemId` make it working.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me I am using `2.4.1` version of `androidx.navigation:navigation-*`

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.mainFragment, R.id.recentsFragment, R.id.favouriteFragment
                -> {
                    // do your Code
                }
                else -> {
                   //do your code
                }
            }
            Log.i("TLogs", "onCreate: ${bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId}")
        }
```

You can check it according to the example I have done and attached.

Log is showing the current item Id

Comment: If I press in the icons, the fragment will change. But if I use selectedItemId to change the fragment, stuff won't work :(

Comment: ohh so that was the problem